# WP7 - Maps - edit attribute of pushpin template at runtime

Tags: windows-phone-7, datatemplate, bing-maps, silverlight-toolkit, pushpin

I am developing the mapping functionality of our WP7 application. currently the pushpins appear as a circle graphic.

I am trying to create functionality to allow the user to be able to change the size of the circle of the pushpin, by sliding a bar. The idea being that the user can change the size of the pushpin anywhere between two sizes.

Therefore I don't want to create 2 or 3 pre-defined pushpin templates in XAML, and simply swap between them - I want to be able to modify an attribute of the template (specifically the height and width of the ellipse) in real time as the user slides a bar, or holds down on the page, or whatever.

However, I have been struggling to do this.

Is it possible to edit an attribute of an existing template? I have looked into creating a template in real time but this does not appear to be the solution, either.

Depending on the customer, the amount of pushpins that will appear on the page could vary by quite an amount. Also, our customers are outdoor types, and many struggle with smaller icons, whereas others don't. Hence my desire for this functionality.

Please find the XAML below, I simply wish to alter the size of the ellipse at run time. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
      <ControlTemplate x:Key="PushpinControlTemplate1" TargetType="my:Pushpin">
        <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" Width="50" Height="50" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                <Grid MinHeight="31" MinWidth="29" Margin="0">
                    <Ellipse Fill="#FFFF7F00"
                   Margin="1"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Width="50"
                   Height="50"
                   Stroke="White"
                   StrokeThickness="3"/>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                       ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                       Margin="4"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind a Height property to the ViewModel's propetry.

```
   <Ellipse 
           Width="50"
           Height="{Binding ItemHeight}"/>
```

And change the property, when user slides the bar.

Comment: Thanks, @Anton. Unfortunately we have no used an MVVM design patter, and the template is bound to a pushpin, by simple saying: 

`code`pushpin.Template = this.Resources["PushpinControlTemplate1"] as ControlTemplate;

So I am unsure how to alter an attribute of the ellipse, for example by binding it to a variable in the code behind.

Answer (score 1):

```
private DataTemplate CreateDataTemplate()
{
    string xaml =
        @"<DataTemplate
        xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
        xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"">
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Fill=""LightGreen"" Height=""50"" Width=""250"" />
            <TextBlock Text='{Binding}' FontSize='40' />
            </Grid>       
        </DataTemplate>";
    DataTemplate dt = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
    return dt;
}
```

you can refer above code...

[Click](http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-dynamically-generating-datatemplate-in-code)

.................................................................

binding your property

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have successfully added my controltemplate to the code behind, and have bound my pushpins to it. However, I am still left with the problem of how to change an attribute of the controltemplate on the fly. For example, changing ellipse width to 30.